# Recursively Define & Prove Through Strong Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

hopefully you guys will be able to help me.

I need to recursively define $a_n = 6a_{n-1}-9a_{n-2}$, and prove $a_n=(5-n)\cdot3^n$ $a_0 = 5$ and  $a_1 = 12$

I've already done the basis case for this induction problem, but I am stuck on the second induction step. I know the following though:

$a_k(rec)=a_k(exp)$, for all $i = 0,1,2,3,\ldots,k$.

Prove $a_{k+1}(rec)=a_{k+1}(exp)$

asub(k+1) = (5-(k+1))3^(k+1) = 6(5-k)3^k - 9(5-(k+1)3^(k-1)

I don't even know if I did this correct, but this problem seems a lot harder than the other recursion problems that I have done.

Comment: What means asub, rec, exp?

Comment: recursive and expected

Comment: Still I dont understand. Recursive and expected, by themselves, doesnt mean something on math. I assume you are using some kind of informatic language.

Comment: Rec is the original definition with asub(n) = 6asub(n-1)-9asub(n-2)
Exp is what I am trying to prove with asub(n)=(5-n)*3^n

I guess it kind of isn't required, that's just how I was taught.

Comment: Maybe you are on the way. In principle you are using strong induction. In the notation you are using, you want to prove that $6(5-k)3^k -9(5-(k-1))3^{k-1}=(5-(k+1))3^{k+1}$. Note that you had it slightly wrong.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah ok yes, so through algebra I'd have to make the left equal the right correct?

Comment: @daniel death: Yes, that's right. The algebra is fairly  straightforward.

Comment: Ok I am going to try and then post my results.

Comment: I don't like to type math in comments, but I will try. Note that $6(5-k)3^k=2(5-k)3^{k+1}$ and $9(5-(k-1))3^{k-1}=(5-(k-1))3^{k+1}$. Combining, we get $[2(5-k)-(5-(k-1))]3^{k+1}$, and the stuff in front of $3^{k+1}$ simplifies to $5-k-1$ which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you're using information in the wrong order.

$a_{k+1} = 6a_k - 9a_{k-1}$ because of the recursive definition.

Your assumption gives you formulas for $a_k$ and $a_{k-1}$ but not for $a_{k+1}$. However, you can substitute these formulas, to get
$a_{k+1} = 6(5-k)\cdot 3^k - 9\cdot (5-(k-1))\cdot 3^{k-1}$. (This is what I think is meant by $rec$).

Now do some algebra and make the right-hand side look like $(5-(k+1))\cdot3^{k+1}$, (which is what I think you mean by $exp$).

Comment: Yes. Then combine powers of 3.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n-3a_{n-1}=3(a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2})=\cdots=3^{n-1}(a_1-3a_0)$$
$$a_n-3a_{n-1}=3^{n-1}(a_1-3a_0)$$
$$3a_{n-1}-3^2a_{n-2}=3\cdot3^{n-2}(a_1-3a_0)$$
$$\cdots$$
$$3^{n-1}a_1-3^na_0=3^{n-1}\cdot3^0(a_1-3a_0)$$
Adding side by side,
$$a_n-3^na_0=n\cdot3^{n-1}(a_1-3a_0)$$
$$a_n=n\cdot3^{n-1}a_1-(n-1)\cdot3^na_0$$